# Facing Issue while launching grunt from command prompt

Tags: javascript

Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR >> SyntaxError: Unexpected string Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.  Aborted due to warnings. getting this error while launching grunt from command promt can anybody help on this issue?

my Gruntfile.js file is:-

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({

require('time-grunt')(grunt);


require('jit-grunt')(grunt);


grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


  jshint: {
    options: {
      jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
      reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
    },

    all: {
      src: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        'app/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    }
  }
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
  'jshint'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default',['build']);

  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try including this?

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.registerTask('build', [
  'jshint'
]);
```

Comment: it is solved, actually i have added                                                   
require('time-grunt')(grunt);
require('jit-grunt')(grunt); this two lines inside grunt.initConfig which must come outside that loop. thanks for your effort.

Comment: Yes, Also you are having two grunt.initConfig.
You should remove that top one and keep only one grunt.initConfig.
Kudos!!